# Navigator changing color in browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, xpages

I have simple xpage with dynamic views. I can switch between them via Navigator that I added from Extension Library. Everything works OK, but the problem is with the CSS. To the navigator I have 1 style sheet attached, which contains the following:

```
.lotusSelected{background-color:none;}
```

And this is where it gets interesting- whenever I open the xpage in Chrome web browser, try to open any of the navigator elements and look at the code via Chrome devkit (or whatever it is when you press F12) it shows that the code above now is:

```
.lotusSelected{background-color:red;}
```

...So it pretty much changes my CSS. I don't understand why this is happening. Also, it does not happen in Internet Explorer. Can anyone explain me why this occurs and how do I fix it?

Comment: CSS styles will occur which is last in stylsheets.

Comment: @stanze i don't think you understood what I ment. I don't have the background-color:red; property in my CSS. I don't understand where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your css style is being overwritten by another one (i.e. from OneUI)
Check if it appears with strikethrough style below in your css debugger.

In that case, you can add !important in your style:

.lotusSelected{background-color:none !important;}

(FYI: this is a css anti-pattern :P )

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll check this later and post the progress.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the background-color to be nothing then use transparent instead of none.

Comment: Still it does not explain where it got the red color. I just created new CSS file and everything works ok.

Comment: Then check with e.g. Chrome dev tools where in which CSS file the red color comes from. Click on the red element and inspect it.